# Can't deploy Play application into Heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku, playframework

I'm having issues deploying a Play application into Heroku. I've had no problems deploying other basic applications without modules, but this one is giving me the following error:

```
@ubuntu:~/$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 812, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (699/699), done.
Writing objects: 100% (794/794), 2.00 MiB, done.
Total 794 (delta 145), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Play! app detected
-----> Installing ivysettings.xml..... done
-----> Building Play! application...
       ~        _            _ 
       ~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
       ~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
       ~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
       ~ |_|            |__/   
       ~
       ~ play! 1.2.3, http://www.playframework.org
       ~
       1.2.3
       Play! application root found at ./mods/playcopy/crud-1.2.3/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/use-gs-in-tags/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/demo/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/inline-dependency-declaring/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/jquery-ui/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/booking/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/less-and-coffee/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/chat/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/
./
       Resolving dependencies: .play/play dependencies ./mods/playcopy/crud-1.2.3/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/use-gs-in-tags/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/demo/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/inline-dependency-declaring/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/jquery-ui/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/booking/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/less-and-coffee/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/chat/
./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/
./ --forceCopy --silent -Duser.home=/tmp/build_1hn7e8ahaqrso 2>&1
       ~ Resolving dependencies using /tmp/build_1hn7e8ahaqrso/mods/playcopy/crud-1.2.3/conf/dependencies.yml,
       ~
       ~
       ~ No dependencies to install
           ~
       ~ Done!
       ~
       ~        _            _ 
       ~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
       ~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
       ~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
       ~ |_|            |__/   
       ~
       ~ play! 1.2.3, http://www.playframework.org
       ~
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 64: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/use-gs-in-tags/: is a directory
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 65: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/demo/: is a directory
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 66: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/inline-dependency-declaring/: is a directory
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 67: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/jquery-ui/: is a directory
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 68: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/booking/: is a directory
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 69: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/less-and-coffee/: is a directory
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 70: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/samples-and-tests/chat/: is a directory
/app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 71: ./mods/playcopy/greenscript-1.2.6h/: is a directory
       /app/slug-compiler/lib/../language_packs/play/bin/compile: line 72: ./: is a directory
 !     Failed to build Play! application
 !     Cleared Play! framework from cache
/app/slug-compiler/lib/language_pack.rb:35:in `block in compile': failed to compile Play! app (Slug::CompileError)
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/language_pack.rb:32:in `fork'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/language_pack.rb:32:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:490:in `block in run_language_pack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:117:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:727:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:489:in `run_language_pack'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:98:in `block in timeout'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:98:in `rescue in timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:93:in `timeout'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:99:in `block in compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/utils.rb:117:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:727:in `log'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:98:in `compile'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:85:in `block in <main>'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:498:in `block in lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `call'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/repo_lock.rb:44:in `run'
    from /app/slug-compiler/lib/slug.rb:498:in `lock'
    from /app/slug-compiler/bin/slugc:66:in `<main>'
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compiled slug size is 36.4MB
-----> Launching... done, v6
       http://billeteo.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:billeteo.git
   53b789c..24f66a4  master -> master
```

Although I'm running from the root of my project, Heroku believes that my root is at:

```
 Play! application root found at ./mods/playcopy/crud-1.2.3/
```

which, of course, doesn't contain the code and the process fails.

My application is standard Play app with the following dependencies.xml:

```
# Application dependencies
# Notes:
#   play is an alias for play -> play $currentVersion
#   play -> crud is an alias for play -> crud $currentVersion
#   play -> secure is an alias for play -> secure $currentVersion
#   Modules from the main repository use 'play' as organisation

require:
    - play
    - playcopy -> crud 1.2.3
    - playcopy -> betterlogs 1.0
    - playcopy -> cobertura 2.1
    - playcopy -> mockito 0.1
    - playcopy -> greenscript 1.2.6h
    - custom -> useragentcheck 1.0
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-search 3.4.0.Final

repositories:
     - localModules:
         type:       local
         artifact:   "${application.path}/mods/[organisation]/[module]-[revision]"
         contains:
           - playcopy
           - custom
```

I'm using a local repository for some official Play modules as they may have some custom code (remove some unnecessary classes, change security, some logs, etc).

Anyone knows how to make Heroku find the right root? Could not find anything on Google...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Play setup on Heroku didn't anticipate your particular setup here.  Like you indicated, it's confused about where the root of your application is.  I think we can push a fix to resolve this, but in the mean time, you should be able to work around it.  Try this:

Zip your custom modules and change your dependencies.yml file to

```
...
repositories:
 - localModules:
     type:       local
     artifact:   "${application.path}/mods/[organisation]/[module]-[revision].zip"
     contains:
       - playcopy
       - custom
...
```

During dependency resolution, Play should unzip your custom modules and put them in the right place.  Also, Heroku shouldn't get confused about where the root of your app is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I'm getting another error: 

20:55:58,442 ERROR ~ Precompiled classes are missing!!

Any idea? Btw, Heroku just got ++love by checking SO and answering in here ;)

Comment: Hard to know what's going on exactly with the precompile.  Could you log a ticket to Heroku so I can take a look at your app?  I'll be sure to re-post anything we find to SO :)

Comment: Actually, before you log the ticket, you can try running the compile just like Heroku does.  There's no magic going on really:

Comment: Blarg.  Hit enter too soon.  Check out this post to see how to reproduce the Heroku compile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560628/play-cant-read-heroku-config-vars-when-parsing-application-conf